# Rename layers in geopackage in R

Tags: r, r-sf

Is it possible to directly rename layers of a geopackage in R without 1) reading in the layer, 2) copying it back to same database with a new name, and 3) deleting the original layer?

PseudoCode

```
library(sf)

geopackage = "example.gpkg"

lyrs = st_layers(geopackage)
lyrs
# Driver: GPKG 
# Available layers:
#   layer_name geometry_type features fields
# 1      Layer1_old Multi Polygon        1      1
# 2      Layer2_old Multi Polygon        1      1
# 3      Layer3_old Multi Polygon        1      1


### I'm looking for something like so I can cycle through
st_rename(geopackage, layer = lyrs[1], new.name = "Layer1_new")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an interesting problem. As far as I know there is no generic function in `{sf}` and friends to rename layers.

But - and here it gets interesting! - the Geopackage file is special. It is, at the same time,

- a spatial data file and
- a regular SQLite database.

Meaning we can hack it with our SQL toolset (ALTER TABLE, I'm looking at you!).

So consider this piece of code, built on the well known & much loved North Carolina shapefile that ships with `{sf}`.

What it does is that it runs alter table on the nc layer (note that the "nc" in this context is driven by the name of the R object used to create the geopackage; in your use case the names will be already given).

After the alter table has been run (and the name of the layer object altered) there needs to be done a small cleanup on the gpkg_contents and gpkg_geometry_columns objects to reflect the update performed. Again familiar SQL stuff.

```
library(sf)
library(DBI)
library(RSQLite)

# the one & only NC shapefile...
nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")) 

# ...saved as a geopackage
st_write(nc, "nc.gpkg")

# check layers name
st_layers("nc.gpkg")

# Driver: GPKG 
# Available layers:
#   layer_name geometry_type features fields crs_name
# 1         nc Multi Polygon      100     14    NAD27

# connect to nc.gpkg as to a sqlite database
con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), "nc.gpkg")

result <- dbSendQuery(con, "ALTER TABLE nc RENAME to CN;")
dbClearResult(result) # you don't really care about the results, but they need to be "handled"

# align other features / see http://www.geopackage.org/spec120/#features
result <- dbSendQuery(con, "update gpkg_contents set table_name = 'CN' where table_name = 'nc';")
dbClearResult(result)
result <-  dbSendQuery(con, "update gpkg_geometry_columns set table_name = 'CN' where table_name = 'nc';")
dbClearResult(result)

# our work is done... let's not keep the connection hanging
dbDisconnect(con)

# read the newly created CN layer
shape <- st_read("nc.gpkg",
                 layer = "CN")

# check results / does it look as the nc.shp we all know & love?
plot(st_geometry(shape))
```

[image: counties of north carolina as stored in nc.shp]

Comment: I think this method would be faster for large or complex geopackages.  I ended up writing a function to do it with the packages I already had loaded `rename_layer = function(dsn, layer, name.new){
  v.lyr = st_read(dsn, layer)
  st_delete(dsn, layer, quiet = TRUE)
  st_write(v.lyr, dsn, name.new)
}` but it has the disadvantage of having to load and write all of the vector layers so is slower.

Comment: @BrianFisher I agree; it is likely safer as well. There is stuff that happens on the background automatically - like building of spatial indices - and this may be put out of whack by a direct database access. I like the idea of a direct SQL access, but it is risky as hell... :)

Comment: Thanks, the info about the background changes is helpful!

Comment: Can you do the the `dbSendQuery` calls within a transaction so that if the process fails at any point the DB isn't left inconsistent? Does SQLite support transactions?

Comment: @Spacedman yes, you could do that. Both SQLite and DBI support transactions. But the main risk I see is not with the two updates - these two tables are obligatory in gpkg format,  so little scope for a failure - but with spatial index (rtree). This is an extension that may - and may not - be implemented in the gpkg file in question. So it needs to be checked and if present renamed. Otherwise the performance of the gpkg would be degraded (resulting in performance, not data, loss - but still an inconvenience).